# Adding menu items?

Tags: menus

I'm having a couple issues I can't resolve with my Wordpress site.

First of all, I'm using "Weaver II 1.1.3" theme, free version. I recently installed Role Scoper (http://agapetry.net/news/introducing-role-scoper/), to try to manage the people that update my site.

In 'Role Scoper', I can control who edits on each page so I made a group that could edit (not publish), and a group that had control to edit AND publish, both ONLY within their department, thus not giving some people the right to actually publish their content (department heads are supposed to "approve" what has been edited by the people below them).

I had all of this set up, and when testing with the lower user level, I edited a page and saved as "Pending Review". When I opened the actual page up, it had added all of the children items underneath that page to my main menu on each page (completely screwing up the whole page).

I logged into the next-highest level (department head level), and approved the edit... only for the page to go back to how it used to be (with the edits I made, nonetheless), the menu not messed up anymore.

My process is okay... and I accomplished what I wanted, but during that span of time where something hasn't been approved, my menu is going to be adding children items that don't fit, until this is fixed. Any ideas? Sometimes Wordpress has a mind of its own.